# Using HttpListener.GetContextAsync() to process requests in parallel

Tags: c#, async-await, httplistener

I am trying to get a HttpListener to accept multiple requests in a parallel manner, using an async - await technique. I am aware that in this case "parallel" execution may be limited to "waiting" time, not "processing" time - and this is OK in this case.

The listener itself is managed within a BackgroundService class. At the heart of the logic there is a listening loop as follows (simplified and with a lot of logging removed):

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    ...
    while (true)
    {
        var context = await listener.GetContextAsync();
        var processTask = ProcessRequestAsync(context);
    }
    ...
}
```

The processing function looks like this (simplified and with a lot of logging removed):

```
private async Task ProcessRequestAsync(HttpListenerContext context)
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
    context.Response.Close();
}
```

As of my current understanding, within the loop the first line should block until there is a request to process, while the second line should **not** block, instead the processing function in executed until the *await* is reached, then execution continues, and the loop is repeated with *GetContextAsync()* being called again.

I would expect that a second request, received within the 5 seconds of waiting by the first request, would be executed immediately (until its own 5 seconds of waiting). If the two requests are made within a second, processing both would thus take ~6 seconds.

What happens instead: the second call to *GetContextAsync()* occurs timely as expected, but *await*-ing it blocks until the response of the *HttpListenerContext* returned by the first call is **closed**. This causes the two requests to be processed in sequence, taking 10 seconds instead of 6.

This behavior is suggested by another test I did: by moving the *await Task.Delay()* **below** *Response.Close()* , the second *await GetContextAsync()* no longer blocks, that is it returns immediately as the request is received. This suggests that blocking is not task-related (the duration of the task is identical in the two cases), but rather *HttpListenerContext*-related.

However, I could not find this behavior documented anywhere...

Has anyone come across this problem? I found a few other similar questions on SO and several solutions suggested - from basic to very sophisticated - but in the end all seem to follow the same principle as the above code - which does not work.

In the past I solved this problem with explicit threading management (and sadly said, it seemed easier) but I am specifically interested whether this can be done with async - await.

A few end notes:

- Some posters suggested using *.configureAwait(false)*, which I tried but made no difference.
- I logged the thread used by the processing functions and it is the same. However, I don't know whether this is the cause of the problem or its effect (once the 2 calls are scheduled sequentially, there is no harm in executing both on the same thread).

**UPDATES**

I did more tests and it keeps getting worse, it looks more and more like a hard limitation of the listener class. To be sure of the results, I splitted the waiting time into halves, 5 seconds before the HTTP response is closed and 5 seconds after that. As a result, two "parallel" request processing operations are overlapped by 5 seconds, meaning that request #2 can only be processed after response #1 was closed.

I got this same result:

- With the code above, including the suggested improvement using *Task.Run()*
- With the older approach to asynchronous processing (*BeginGetContext* - *EndGetContext*)
- With a *Thread*-based implementation (each context being processed in a different thread)
- With the code sample included in a related but very old discussion [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/694501b9-732c-4ba2-bb6c-25165286abd6/httplistener-begingetcontext-does-not-seem-to-handle-more-than-2-request-simultaneously?forum=netfxnetcom) which was UI-based but I converted it to console app.

All tests were included in very basic console apps, thus the original program being part of a *BackgroundService* is probably **not** related to this problem.

As everything seems to revolve around the listener and the listener context (processing of context #2 being processed only after processing of context #1 completes), the problem boils down to whether there is any way to "unlock" context #1 so that context #2 can be processed. I tried - and failed - to achieve this in two **naive** (and not necessarily usable in production environment) approaches:

- Closing the *HttpListener.Request.InputStream* => no changes at all
- Having the requests served by multiple listeners => failed to start listening on same port (but I suspect this would have gone around the original problem)

Comment: What is the setup here? Console? WPF? Winform? Service? In particular, what is SynchronizationContext.Current? Is it null or non-null?

Comment: Have you tried `_ = Task.Run(() => ProcessRequestAsync(context));` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell I agree, but why the discard?

Comment: @anastaciu if you await then you will encounter the same problem OP is trying to solve, but now with a clear reason.

Comment: @Evk ok, but in that case why the discard at all, why not just `Task.Run(() => ProcessRequestAsync(context));`

Comment: @anastaciu because compiler\analyzer will complain (will issue a warning) that you do not await a `Task` in a context where it can be awaited. And with discard (or any other variable, but since you are not going to use it anyway - discard is best fit) you clarify that you understand what you are doing and do not want to await anyway.

Comment: What .NET version you are using?

Comment: Sorry for the missing pieces of information in my original post. Dotnet version is net6.0. The program is a worker run as console application. SynchronizationContext is NULL both at the listener loop level and the *ProcessRequestAsync()* function. Is this a problem?

The *Task.Run()* version works the same as my original program, that is *GetcontextAsync()* returns the second context only after the first one has been processed. The discard is a nice touch though, thanks, this answers another question of mine.

Again, this looks to me more like a listener problem than a async - await one.

Comment: `HttpListener` should not be behaving that way, and there's nothing I can see wrong with the code, either. Please post a minimal but complete example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I set up a very basic - and definitely **not** production-grade example in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ehm2097/fc1c4dae96d669ab096aece2326c9e6e)